# How to send http request using bash net redirection to a URL with a path?

Tags: bash, networking

Using bash net redirection, I am able to send a simple get to any server, like so:

```
:> /dev/tcp/localhost/3306
```

However, I wish to do something a bit more complicated, which is sending a request to a URL with a path. I tried the following:

```
:> /dev/tcp/url/50070/webhdfs/v1/user/user_name/new_file?user.name=user_name&op=READ
```

Which throws:

```
[1] 69
root@9ec4a825d97d:/# *bash: 50070/webhdfs/v1/user/user_name/new_file?user.name=user_name: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
bash: /dev/tcp/url/50070/webhdfs/v1/user/user_name/new_file?user.name=user_name: Invalid argument
```

Same goes if the URL (which contains a `&`) is quoted.

How, if possible, may I achieve sending a request to an URL with a path using bash net redirection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash` (like in ksh where that feature initially comes from), opening `/dev/tcp/host/port` creates and connects a TCP socket.

You can send a HTTP request on top of that, but you have to write it in the HTTP protocol by hand, like:

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/host/port # connected TCP socket on fd 3
printf >&3 '%s\r\n' 'GET /some/path?query HTTP/1.0' \
                    'Host: host' \
                    'Connection: close' \
                    ''
cat <&3 # read the response
exec 3<&- # close the connection
```

Or the `zsh` equivalent:

```
zmodload zsh/net/tcp
ztcp -d3 host port
printf >&3 '%s\r\n' 'GET /some/path?query HTTP/1.0' \
                    'Host: host' \
                    'Connection: close' \
                    ''
cat <&3 # read the response
ztcp -c 3 # close the connection
```

Note that's HTTP without encryption, so text only which is relatively easy. To do HTTPS, you'd need to write binary data in the TLS protocol which is virtually impossible without using dedicated tools (which would be able to create the TCP connections by themselves in a much better way) such as `socat` or `openssl s_client`, and then there'd be no reason not to use tools dedicated to making HTTP(S) requests such as `curl`, `wget`, `perl`'s `LWP`, `elinks`, `w3m`, `lynx`...